# Weird fragment lifecycle error

Tags: android, android-fragments

**EDIT**

So it seems that my `Fragment` is retained in the `FragmentManager` which tries to reinitialize it. Still not sure why it isn't destroyed with the `Activity`. As for the loading message, this is displayed when the ListView does not have an adapter set. I however, set the adapter items in `onCreate` and `onResume` so I'm not sure why this loading screen is showing. Still open to any explanations of this behavior

**Original**

I'm playing around with fragments and noticed a weird error that is popping up when I change the orientation of the screen. This error should not be happening though because all the data is recreated in the onCreate when the screen orientation is changed. Also, the fragment `onResume()` is called twice after the rotation. Here's my steps for creating the error and how the debugger is hitting the functions.

- Activity: onCreate()
- Activity: onResume()
- Fragment: onResume()
- Rotate Screen
- Activity: onCreate()
- Activity: onResume()
- Fragment: onResume() (items are null even though Activity.onResume() set them)
- Fragment: onResume() (items are not null, why is this being called twice?)

After this last fragment `onResume` is hit, the tablet displays a **"Loading..."** message and icon. Why is the data not displayed in the list any more? My suspicions are that the onCreate is creating a second fragment. The first fragment looses its data because of the orientation destroying the views, the second fragment gets the data and the loading screen is the first fragment with no data items and the second fragment is hidden. I may be wrong. Why aren't the fragments all destroyed when the screen is rotated like the `Activity`? Please do not critique the code unless its to solve this specific issue. I'm not actually making an app, I'm experimenting with fragment functionality. Thanks!

**Main Activity**

```
private ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
private MyListFragment mylistFragment;

public MainActivity() {
    items.add("Hello");
    items.add("World");
    items.add("Goodbye");
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    mylistFragment = new MyListFragment();
    mylistFragment.setItems(items);

    ft.add(R.id.container, mylistFragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mylistFragment.setItems(items);
    mylistFragment.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

**List Fragment**

```
private List<Object> items = null;
private Boolean isSet = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if( !isSet && items != null) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getActivity(), R.layout.item, items));
        isSet = true;
    }
}

public void setItems(List<Object> items) {
    this.items = items;
    if( this.isResumed() ) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getActivity(), R.layout.item, items));
        isSet = true;
    } else {
        isSet = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FragmentManager` will automatically recreate the `Fragment` for me. However, the data inside them needs to be reinitialized. Therefore my code was creating a second fragment. The loading screen was because the first fragment no longer had its adapter of items and the second fragment was hidden. What a headache, I almost think the `FragmentManager` should destroy the `Fragments` so you can recreate them with the data they hold.

Comment: Sorry however I do not see the answer too clearly... how did you end up solving this problem? I came to the same conclusion as you however I can not find a way to easily resolve this issue. Meaning how do you kill the old fragments and use the new ones which were recreated.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the old Fragment and use the new, use the FragmentTransaction.replace() function. Then the old one will be replaced with the new one. Just know that the data will have to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is why in the various demos via Diane and other google examples... they typically have some way of helping hte initialization via a static method... and setArguments.

IIRC, the fragment creation stuff will call the default constructor to create, but only knows about populating with appropriate data via setArguments. In the example on the android development blog... the id was being passed from the listactivity, to the details fragment. After setParams is called, the fragmentManager should be able to reanimate it.

Documentation seems to be sparse on the subject and I'd like to be doing things right, so if you guys have feedback, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using `FragmentActivity` from the support library saves and restores instance automatically. Therefore, only do your fragment transactions if `savedInstanceState` is `null`.

For example, in your `FragmentActivity`'s `onCreate()`, do the following:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment).commit(); //mFragment is your own defined fragment
}
```